# parse.com signup error toast flash for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

I'm creating an android app in eclipse with a service on Parse.com on backend,

On the 'login-password' screen, it works finr, and flashes toast that no user exists, please sign up.

On the sign up activity, the form gets submitted, but the toast shows the 'error' part, and data doesn't gets saved to the parse backend.
Please help.
here's the code

**ParseStarterProjectActivity.java**

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
    EditText Username,Password;
    Button Login,Signup;
    String usernametxt,passwordtxt;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                usernametxt = Username.getText().toString();
                passwordtxt = Password.getText().toString();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernametxt, passwordtxt,
                        new LogInCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (user != null) {
                            // If user exist and authenticated, send user to Welcome.class
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,
                                                   WelcomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Logged in",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No such user exist, please signup",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

**SignupActivity.java**

```
package com.parse.starter;


import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignupActivity extends Activity {
    EditText name,password,confirmpass,email;
    Button signup;
    String usertxt,passwordtxt,emailtxt,confirmpasstxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                usertxt = name.getText().toString();
                passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();
                emailtxt = email.getText().toString();
                 if (usertxt.equals("") && passwordtxt.equals("") && emailtxt.equals(""))
                 {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please complete the sign up form",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                    user.setUsername("username");
                    user.setPassword("password");
                    user.setEmail("email");
                    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                              if (e == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Signed up, please log in.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sign up Error", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                        }
                    });
                 }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

What possibly might have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you got answer getting same isues

Comment: No not yet as visible on stack overflow, however I re-did entire code, and it started working. Difference, I made it using php. Hence android out of context @Erum

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working but the only thing you did wrong is that you set the data in the parse user with input that you gave not what the user gave by putting it in "" marks just refer to it using a variable like this

```
      *.setUsername(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

write the key's value in your class file with

```
parse.initialize(this,"app_id","client_id");
```